# how can use custom routePrefix alexusmai laravel file manager?

Tags: laravel

When I change the file-manager.php to 'routePrefix' => 'file' or 'routePrefix' => 'admin.file' the fm-button page still sends the following request.
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/file-manager/initialize

I changed the routes.php file as follows and only the routes was modified but the requests within the routes were not modified.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'admin'], function () { 
  Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'file-manager', 'namespace' => 'Alexusmai\LaravelFileManager\Controllers', ], function () {...
```

[image]

Comment: What is the action value of your form?

Comment: Try caching the routes `php artisan route:cache`